Sound System (speaker and mic) not working after deleting alsa config file ubuntu
I deleted the ALSA config file while trying to fix some programmatic errors - post which my sound system is not being recognized at all. No audio is playing. My guess is the microphone is not working either. Image shows that input and output devices are not recognized
I tried to reinstall alsa and pulse audio using the following commands:
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base
sudo apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
sudo reboot

I also tried :
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo alsa force-reload


Neither of this seems to work:
aplay -l

gives the following output:
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
ALSA lib conf.c:4553:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
ALSA lib control.c:1528:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL hw:0
aplay: device_list:283: control open (0): No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4553:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
ALSA lib control.c:1528:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL hw:1
aplay: device_list:283: control open (1): No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4553:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
ALSA lib control.c:1528:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL hw:2
aplay: device_list:283: control open (2): No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4553:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
ALSA lib control.c:1528:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL hw:3
aplay: device_list:283: control open (3): No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4553:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
ALSA lib control.c:1528:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL hw:4
aplay: device_list:283: control open (4): No such file or directory
Edit:
Update:
I booted into a live ISO and found the audio to be working fine. So i copy pasted the alsa config file into my existing Ubuntu installation, so now aplay -l is giving:
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC245 Analog [ALC245 Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
Audio Settings
Settings has changed as so, and I am able to play audio through chrome i.e youtube videos; however the "Test" button to test audio through settings is still not working. Not sure what the issue is.
